# Remove noisy and redundant features

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, data-mining, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I have extracted features from a video sequence based on facial markers as means and standard deviations of those markers over a video sequence. They need to be classified into four different classes based on those markers.

In all I have a feature set of around 260 features. How should I determine which features are noisy and redundant in my set. I read about it in some research papers and some of them used the plus l take away r algorithm that I found to be quite appropriate but in such algorithms they always rate one feature against the other and say its good or bad compared to it. 
How do I rate my features to be good or bad? What criterion are used for that generally?

I researched a lot for a couple of days but found nothing clear cut and useful. Would be grateful for the help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Think of your 260 features as a basis for a 260 dimensional room. However, your basis-vectors are not normal to each other so they contain a lot of redundant information. You'd like to transform these vectors into a vector-set where all vectors are normal to each other, thus minimizing the dimensions without losing (much) information.

This is what [Principal component analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) does.

[Linear discriminant analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis) may also be of interest to you.

Comment: Those are for reduction. I do know about those but currently I have to apply something based on a SFS or SBS or the combination of both SFBS.
My problem is I do know those algorithms how do I use a distance criterion to discriminate between my features.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pca or you can train some classifiers, and after this you loop all over yours features adding a big value to each feature, testing if this alteration changes the precision of the classifier, if not, you can remove this feature, after remove all the redundat features, and then retrain your classifiers!

Its a good ideia to train not one classifier but a lot of them, and them make your prediction based on votes, you can user MODE function in matlab to do this!

Answer (score 0):

Use classification rate to determine a subset of feature how much good. You have 260 feature and then have 2^260 subset, this is too much! and search in this space is very difficult. Thus it's better to remove some feature by Filter method (for example FA, t-test, fisher and ...) and then use your search method to find best subset of feature.
Plus l take away r algorithm (or other search algorithm) find various subset and rate it (in this stage use classification rate) and at last specify which subset is better.